# javascript onbeforeunload disable for links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need your help. I'm working with JavaScript and I'm not able to configure how to work on `window.onbeforeunload`.

here's my simple code:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () { 
      if (!confirm("some message here")) { 
          return "Are you sure?"; 
      } else{ 
        return false; 
      } 
}
```

I just need to work the code in closing the browser, reloading page and or exiting tab menu. I need that it will not also work on any links when I press links in my web body or page. Do you have any idea or solution for this?

I hope you can help me with this. I appreciate your kindness.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try that:

```
$(document).on('mousedown', 'a[href]', offBeforeUnload)
    .on('mouseleave', 'a[href]', function () {
        $(window).on('beforeunload', windowBeforeUnload);
    });



function offBeforeUnload(event) {
    $(window).off('beforeunload');
}

function windowBeforeUnload() {
     if (!confirm("some message here")) { 
          return "Are you sure?"; 
      } else{ 
        return false; 
      } 
}

$(window).on('beforeunload', windowBeforeUnload);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Wfk2W/show/)

Comment: Hi, it's really awesome and it's working on you. but, I don't know why it's not working when I tried it. Can you please help me how to do that? thank you so much

Comment: Any error in console? You should provide the new code you are using, you must be doing something wrong, somewhere

Comment: Hi Wolff, I know I'm disturbing you right now but I really need your help. it's not really working, I checked all my codes and I think there's no problem with my codes. any some more suggestions? thank you and I appreciate your help.

Comment: I just copy your codes in http://jsfiddle.net/Wfk2W/, that's all. I just created a simple html then I put your codes in my <script type="text/javascript">...</script>. what do you think?

Comment: Have you cleared cache? Have you removed your old code? Have you **any error in console** ???

Comment: yes, I already cleared cache, I don't have old code. the only remaining code is your code. if you don't mind can I ask your email or skype id? so that I can send my codes there?

Comment: Hi, how about if I change this $(document).on('mousedown', 'a[href]', offBeforeUnload) to a submit button? what I mean is the a[href] change to an <input type=submit>. do you know what code I should replace? your code is working fine but that's the only problem I'm encountering that's why I'm trying to replaced the a[href] to a 'submit button'.

Comment: Do you mean: `$(document).on('mousedown', 'a[href],:submit', offBeforeUnload)` ???

Comment: no, it's not an a[href]. what I'm trying to asked is how to replace a[href] code to a button type 'submit'. instead of <a href=""> I will replace this code <input type='submit'> to this code you provided $(document).on('mousedown', 'a[href],:submit', offBeforeUnload). what should I replace in a[href] to a button SUBMIT?

Comment: Well, the code i posted would handle both cases, anchor tags `<a>` and submit buttons. If you want only submit buttons, then just use selector to target submit button: `$(document).on('mousedown', ':submit', offBeforeUnload)`  ... You should read at the basis, comma separator in CSS selector means OR. If still doesn't work, then provide relevant code regarding your issue