# How to disable Warning by "onbeforeunload" when "reload" same page?

Tags: javascript, html

My code works well, but I do not need this "beforeunload warning" when reloadind **same page** (reload button ou F5 key) , or when a **click in the "back"** button...

My original working code:

```
<script>
    window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
        var msg = '\n\n\nARE YOU SURE？\n\n\n';
        e = e || window.event;

        if (e)
            e.returnValue = msg;
        //some extra conditions
        document.getElementById("popUpOut").style.display = 'block';
        return msg;
    }
</script>
```

So, this is my question: How to disable beforeunload in these situations ("back button" and "reload page)?

Comment: What's the use-case? The only really valid use-cases that come to mind for `onbeforeunload` apply equally to reloading the same page as to going elsewhere.

Comment: You are not supposed to know to which page you are going. So no this is not possible.

Comment: Thanks for your attention!  So, that is it!  **reloading** the "same page"  (F5 or reload button)  OR back button... (this last one,  is a demand from a client)

Comment: i was woindering if possible to do some similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932464/javascript-onbeforeunload-disable-for-links

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. A page refresh is like navigating away and unloading the DOM so the onbeforeunload event will always be called but you can prevent it using jquery for keys pressed for Ctrl + R or F5 and Backspace.

For Ctrl + R use this:

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

For F5 use this:

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.which || e.keyCode) == 116) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: Edited my answer above

Comment: That's what i said in my answer YOU CANT disable on reload button on browser and on back button because A page refresh is like navigating away and unloading the DOM so the onbeforeunload event will always be called. You can just prevent the buttons i said. Im glad that it helped you but would be very nice if you vote my answer as the right one if it really helped you.

Comment: As you can see, it is possible to "control" the BACK BUTTON... now I am trying to listening the buttons RELOAD and GO...  I get this info from http://dotnsf.blog.jp/archives/1012215593.html   and   from here http://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/stealing-history-api....

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let me say that, ""I do not want"" stop reloading the page! BUT controll the beforeunload **message**!

So if you allow me, I will try to explain:

- A) I just want do DECIDE in that event I show (or not) the "warning
  exit message"

As far everyone say to me that, "it is impossible" do control UnbeforeUnload event, I make some tests and depending of the browser it is perfecty possible, BUT this is a "working progress rechearch"

So I know this:

- 1) listening the keyboard it's very easy to "chose the event" and,
  what I want do show in the "warning mewssage" for each one.
- 2)    Listening the history I can chose what happends on "Navigator's
  Back    button", dand do the same.
- 3) The code below works fine in chome...

And to control the keyboard, I have this, very simple code in JS:

```
document.onkeydown = KeyCheck;
function KeyCheck(e) {
    var key = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : e.keyCode;
    if(key==116) {flag_beforeunload=false;}     
    if(key==8) {flag_beforeunload=false;}       
    if (e.keyCode == 82 && e.ctrlKey) {flag_beforeunload=false;}        

    document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = "key = "+key + " - " + flag_beforeunload;
}


window.onbeforeunload = function(e){
    var msg = 'You are sure to exit?';
    e = e || window.event;

    if(e)
        if (flag_beforeunload == true) {

            return msg;
        }
}
```

Following, [here (dotnsf site)](http://dotnsf.blog.jp/archives/1012215593.html) is where  I get the code for control the browser's "back button and"... I can even **disable** it.

but it is en Jquery, following is my code, but in JS:

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) {   

 window.history.back(-1)


            if( !event.state ){
            //the to lines below, disable the back button
                //  history.pushState( "nohb", null, "" );
                //  return;

                //  the following line iIcan use to control the envent, in UnBeforeUnload
                // flag_beforeunload=false;

            }
    }
}
```

And finaly, this is my question:
I apreciate more help, and solutions for others navigators than Chrome!

Thanks a lot !